# Proving a Subset Identity: If $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$, then $A\cap C\subseteq C\cap D$ and $A\cup C\subseteq C\cup D$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Working on part A of this problem:

> Prove each of the following results without using Venn diagrams of membership tables. (Assume a universe $\mathscr U$.)
>
> a) If $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$, then $A\cap C\subseteq C\cap D$ and $A\cup C\subseteq C\cup D$.
> b) $A\subseteq B$ if and only of $A\cap\overline B=\emptyset$.
> b) $A\subseteq B$ if and only of $\overline A\cup B=\emptyset$.

I worked out  the first part like this:

1. If $A$ is a subset of $B$ then $\forall~x~[x\in A \implies x\in B]$
2. Same goes for $C$ being a subset of $D$ (If $x$ is in $C$ it is in $D$)
3. If $A\cap C$, then $x\in A \wedge x\in C$
4. $x\in B ~\wedge x\in D$ (From steps $1$ and $2$)
5. Since $A\cap B \implies B\cap D$ we can say $A\cap C \subseteq B\cap D $

I'm wondering if I've made any errors in proving the first part of the consequent?

Comment: It seems right, but the beginning of 5. is gibberish.

Comment: @GitGud What I'm trying to say is that Step 3 implies Step 4. Since x being a member of A and C implies it is a member of B and D, I can say A intersect C is a subset of B intersect D. How would you suggest I improve my clarity?

Comment: Things like $A\cap C$ are sets, and so don't have true/false values. Statement 3, for example, needs to be of the form 'if $A\cap C$ has some property'.

Comment: @Darcy  $\TeX$ tip: use /in for "is in the set", rather than \epsilon, although they do look very similar handwritten!

Comment: @Darcy $A\cap B \to B\cap D$ is saying $A\cap B$ implies $B\cap D$. Sets aren't statements, sets can't imply anything. In 5. I'd just write, from 3. and 4. it follows that $\forall x(x\in A\cap C\to x\in B\cap D)$, that is, $A\cap C\subseteq B\cap D$. In 3. you should add the universal quantifier over $x$. And even though I personally accept the steps until 4., I would prefer to  make everything explicit (e.g. If $A\cap C$, then $\forall xA\cap C(x\in A\land x\in C)$, thus $x\in A$ for all $x\in A\cap C$ and from 2. it follows that $x\in B$. Similarly for the other sets).

Comment: Another related question: [If $A\subset B$ and $C\subset D$, then $A\cap C \subset B\cap D$ and $A'\cap C'\subset B'\cap D'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Starting with $(3)$ I would instead assume $x \in A\cap C$.

  - Then argue as you did (...so $x \in A \land x\in C$; using this together with the implications in $(1), (2)$ from modus ponens we get $x\in B$ and $x\in D$.
  - Conclude $x \in B\cap D$.
- Therefore $x \in A \cap C \rightarrow x \in B\cap D$. (Having assumed $x \in A\cap C$, we derived $x \in B\cap D.$, Hence this implication is justified.)
- Finally we conclude $A\cap C \subseteq B\cap D$.