# Is it true that $A⊆B ∧ C⊆D \Rightarrow A∩C ⊆ B∩D?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this phrase true?

> $A⊆B ∧ C⊆D \Rightarrow A∩C ⊆ B∩D$

In first look there is no connection between $A⊆B$ and $C⊆D$ but $A∩C$ in the worst situation is $∅$ and $∅$ is subset of all sets, so can we say if $A⊆B$ ∧ $C⊆D$, $A∩C$ is subset of $B∩D$?

Comment: Start with $a\in A\cap C$. This means $a\in A\subseteq B$ and $a\in C\subset D$. Try to use MathJax. Here is a 
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See also: [Proving a Subset Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/860535) and [If $A\subset B$ and $C\subset D$, then $A\cap C \subset B\cap D$ and $A'\cap C'\subset B'\cap D'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511797). Both of them are among the [search results in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24A%5Ccap%20C%20%5Csubseteq%20B%5Ccap%20D%24&p=1). Meta: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that whenever we find something in $A \cap C$ it also belongs to $B \cap D$ that is $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap D$

Consider $x \in A \cap C$. You then know that $x$ belongs to $A$ and $C$.

Because $x \in A , x \in B$ because $A \subseteq B $

Similarly for $x \in C$

Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap C \subseteq B\cap C \subseteq B\cap D$.

Alternatively,

$A\cap C \subseteq A\cap D \subseteq B\cap D$.